# Javascript Facebook API /me emails won´t work

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I am currently testing to create a login via facebook. It´s easy to use, but I just don´t get the mail address over the api.

Here is my code, I hope you guys know what could be wrong.

```
/*
    Facebook SDK
*/
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId            : '138095353404106',
        autoLogAppEvents : true,
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v2.9'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
};

function checkLoginState()
{
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)
    {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
};

function statusChangeCallback(response)
{
    if (response.status === 'connected')
    {
        testAPI();
    };
};

function testAPI()
{
    FB.api('/me', {fields: "id,first_name,last_name,email"}, function(response)
    {
        console.log(response);
    });

    FB.api('/me/picture', {type: "large"}, function(response)
    {
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```

ID, First Name and Last Name is there. I just miss the email. No error´s in the console.

PS

Also included HTML Tag:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" onlogin="checkLoginState();" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true"></div>
```

Comment: And where are you asking the user for permission to access their email?

Comment: I forget to tell, that I also add the html tag

<div class="fb-login-button" onlogin="checkLoginState();" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true"></div>

Comment: So you are not asking for the permission at all yet.

Comment: I am really new in that api stuff from facebook. Need I ?

Comment: Of course you do.

Comment: This works fine :) THX!

<div scope="email" class="fb-login-button" onlogin="checkLoginState();" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to add the scope parameter for asking the user also for the email permission:

```
<div scope="email" class="fb-login-button" onlogin="checkLoginState();" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true"></div>
```